# mouseenter and leave with slide

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I want to slideup a div when the mouse hit the minimized element and slide it down when the user leaves it:

```
$('#managerpane').mouseenter(function(){
  $('#managerpane').height(300).slideUp();
});

$('#managerpane').mouseleave(function () {
  $('#managerpane').height(60).slideDown();
});


<div id="managerpane" style="position:absolute;left:10px;bottom:0px;z-index:1000;height:60px; background:white; overflow-x: auto; max-width: 76%;" >
    <div>.childs..</div>
</div>
```

the div slides up and down. What's wrong?

Comment: "dow"? "leaved"? Can you clean up your grammar first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During slideUp your div height becomes 0 (slowly) so that the mouse pointer is no longer over your div. On the next mouse move a leave event is triggered and hence a slideDown,mouse again comes over your div. This result in multiple mouseenter mouseleave events and hence div goes up and down.

1. when mouse is moved triggers a mouseenter event
2. height increased to 300
3. slidesUp height animated to 0
4. which leaves mouse outside the div
5. when mouse is moved triggers a mouseleave event
6. height = 60px;
7. slidesdown to height = 60
8. mouse enters the div. goes to state 1

when you move mouse over this div processes 1-8 happens continously. ie triggers multiple up&down events.

If you want to animate height change

```
$('#managerpane').mouseenter(function(){
$(this).animate({height:300},500);
console.log("enter");
});

$('#managerpane').mouseleave(function () {
$(this).animate({height:60},500);
console.log("leave");
});
```

This works fine. But if you log the event in your snippet you can see multiple events getting fired.

Answer (score 1):

As is clear from the demo below, depending on the location of the mouse pointer, there can be multiple `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. That's why the `div` moves up and down for **a `mouseenter` event**

```js
$('#managerpane').mouseenter(function(){
  $('#managerpane').height(300).slideUp();
});

$('#managerpane').mouseleave(function () {
  $('#managerpane').height(60).slideDown();
});
```

```css
#managerpane {
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="managerpane" style="position:absolute;left:10px;bottom:0px;z-index:1000;height:60px; background:white; overflow-x: auto; max-width: 76%;" >
    <div>.childs..</div>
</div>
```